# Missing Cycles Renderer

Tags: cycles-render-engine

2.90.1, Win 10 64x

Maybe a minor bug, or just an odd glitch:

Did a "simple" project, rendered via Cycles to PNGs, opened a new file, imported my sequence and re-output to mpg... everything went well.

Then I decided to make some minor tweaks, so I reopened my .blend... and somehow the first thing I noticed was my renderer had been switched to Eevee... so I tried to change it but Cycles was missing.  Went into my prefs and Cycles was enabled... but I went ahead and disabled and immediately re-enabled it and saved prefs again (though I have autosave set) and Cycles was available again.

Anyone else?

Sidenote: can't log in to the community... all log in links go to sign up forms, trying a new sign up sends me to a recover password form... round and round...

Comment: Even the Cycles render engine is only an addon - maybe you accidentally disable that addon?

Comment: "...rendered via Cycles" + "Went into my prefs and Cycles was enabled"

Comment: I don't think there is a way to replicate this issue for anyone. If you find a way, you should  describe it in detail in a bug report, Bugs are off topic on BSE though, because there nothing that can be done about them here in an answer.